# Two order related questions for subgroups of infinite groups

Tags: group-theory, order-theory, lattice-orders

For finite groups what I am asking is really trivial. In finite groups if we pick a non trivial subgroup $H$ of $G$ we can always find (there could be multiple choices) a subgroup that is an immediate predecessor (with respect to *inclusion*) and a subgroup that is an immediate successor of $H$.

1) Can we choose for each non trivial subgroup in an infinite group an immediate predecessor/successor?

2) Choose $H<G$. Can we define a procedure that allows to determine a total order including $H$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer:**

1) No. Take for example $G=\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and $H=0\oplus\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. For every subgroup *K* with *H* < *K* ≤ *G*, there is some subgroup *L* with *H* < *L* < *K*, so *H* has no immediate successor. (This is equivalent to saying $\mathbb{Z}$ has no minimal nonzero subgroups.)

2) Yes, if I understand what you want. This is called the [Hausdorff maximal principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_maximal_principle).  Every totally ordered subset (including a single guy, *H*) is contained in a maximal totally ordered subset.  However, this maximal totally ordered subset could be very weird, and need not be discrete.

---

**Classification in abelian case:** Suppose *H* < *K* ≤ *G* are subgroups.  If there is no subgroup *L* with *H* < *L* < *K*, then we say *H* is a maximal subgroup of *K* and that *K* covers *H* in *G*.  The trivial subgroup has no maximal subgroups, and the full group *G* has no covers in *G*.

Call a subgroup "maximal good" if it has a maximal subgroup or if it is the identity subgroup.  Call a subgroup "cover good in *G*" if it is the whole group *G* or if it is a maximal subgroup of a subgroup of *G*.  Call a subgroup of *G* "good" if it is both maximal good and cover good.  Call a group *G* wholesome if every subgroup is good in *G*.

For instance finite groups, Tarski monsters, and torsion DSC groups are wholesome, but groups with a normal infinite cyclic subgroup are not wholesome.

For abelian groups one gets the nice classification:

> An abelian group is wholesome if and only if it is torsion and reduced.

A torsion abelian group is one in which every element has finite order, and a reduced abelian group is one that has no direct summand isomorphic to a direct summand of $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$, a so called [divisible group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisible_group).

---

**Proof of classification in abelian case:**

*Lemma on covers and maximal subgroups in torsion abelian groups:* Suppose *K* is torsion and *H* is a maximal subgroup of *K*.  Then there is some prime *p* such that *pK* ≤ *H* < *K*.  Conversely, if *pK* < *K*, then there is some maximal subgroup *H* of *K* with *pK* ≤ *H* < *K*.  In particular, for *K* to be maximal good it is necessary and sufficient for *pK* < *K*, and for *H* to be cover good in *G* it is necessary and sufficient for $H < (H:p)_G$ where $(H:p)_G = \{ g \in G : pg \in H \}$.

*Wholesome G must be torsion*: Assume by way of contradiction that *G* is not torsion. Let *Z* be an infinite cyclic subgroup, and *H* a subgroup maximal with respect to *Z* ∩ *H* = 0 (which exists by Zorn's lemma or Hausdorff's maximal principal).  Since *H* does not contain all of *Z*, *H* ≠ *G*, and so let *K* ≤ *G* properly contain *H*. By maximality, *K* ∩ *Z* ≠ 0, and so let *z* ≠ 0 be a nonzero element of *K* ∩ *Z*. Consider the subgroup *L* generated by *H* and 2*z*. Since *Z* is infinite cyclic and *z* ≠ 0, 2*z* ≠ 0, and so *H* < *L* ≤ *K*.  However, *z* cannot be written as a sum of *h* + 2*nz* lest *h* = (1−2*n*)*z* lie in *H* ∩ *Z* = 0. Hence *H* < *L* < *K*, and there is no subgroup covering *H*.

*Wholesome G must be reduced*: Let *H* be a divisible summand of *G*. Then *pH* = *H*, so *H* is not maximal good unless *H* = 0. Hence *G* is reduced.

The converse also works:

*G is reduced implies every subgroup of G is maximal good:*  Let *H* be a subgroup of *G*.  Since *G* is reduced, *H* is not divisible, and so there is some prime *p* with *pH* < *H*, and hence *H* has a maximal subgroup.

*G is torsion implies every subgroup of G is cover good in G:*  Let *H* be a proper subgroup of *G*.  Then $G/H$ is a nonzero torsion group, and so has an element *gH* of prime order (take a nonzero element and raise it to the right power).  Then *H* is a maximal subgroup of *K* ≤ *G*, the subgroup generated by *H* and *g*.

Answer (score 3):

Proof that $(\mathbb{Q}, +)$ has no maximal subgroups:

Suppose $M < \mathbb{Q}$ is maximal. Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is abelian, $M$ is a normal subgroup. Thus $\mathbb{Q}/M$ has no proper subgroups ($M$ is maximal), and therefore $\mathbb{Q}/M$ is cyclic of prime order $p$.

We have $[G:M] = p$, so using the left coset action we can find a homomorphism $\phi: \mathbb{Q} \rightarrow S_p$ with $Ker(\phi) \leq M$. Now $S_p$ is finite with order $d = p!$. Then for every $q \in \mathbb{Q}$, we have $\phi(q) = \phi(d \cdot \frac{q}{d}) = \phi(\frac{q}{d} + \cdots + \frac{q}{d}) = \phi(\frac{q}{d})^d = 1$. Thus $Ker(\phi) = \mathbb{Q}$, and $M = \mathbb{Q}$.

This is a contradiction, and thus no such $M$ can exist.

Comment: How did you conclude that $\mathbb Q \cong S_p$ from $\ker \phi = \mathbb Q$?

Comment: Once you state that $\mathbb{Q}/M$ is cyclic of prime order $p$, you know there is something wrong because which $p$ should be singled out for this task (except perhaps 2)? Why would one prime be better than another? Sure, this is no proof, but it was my immediate reaction.

Comment: @JacobSchlather: Yes, that is wrong.. I have no idea what I was thinking there. I have edited my post. This was my original idea, but for some reason I changed it to the wrong one..